# How to use HTML framesets in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view called "chat.html.erb". Now this has a frameset with 2 frames. The code is:

```
<FRAMESET ROWS="65%,35% FRAMEBORDER='0' FRAMESPACING='0'>  

<FRAME NAME="DISP" SRC="CHAT_WINDOW.HTML.ERB">  

<FRAME NAME="TEXT" SRC="CHAT_WINDOW.HTML.ERB">  

</FRAMESET>
```

The two frames are both in the same directory as the chat.html.erb file. When I open the chat.html.erb file in a browser window I can see the stuff fine. But it doesn't get rendered in rails. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get a view rendered in Rails, you need at least the 2 components:

- a Rails controller like `ChatsController`
- a Rails action with a corresponding view like `chat` with the view `chat.html.erb`

You could then call that in your browser (when you have started  your Rails application with `rails s` with `http://localhost:3000/chats/chat`. But you need an extra entry  in your `routes.rb` file like: `get 'chats/chat'` so that Rails can match your URL to the right controller and action.

This is all just speculation, but without code :-) there is not much of a chance ...